# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Character.isAlphabetic(I)Z

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to run a .jar that runs fine on my own computer but gives the following exception on someone else's.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Character.isAlphabetic(I)Z
    at chatai.Word.shrinkEndPunct(Word.java:91)
    at chatai.Word.createWord(Word.java:36)
    at chatai.ChatAI.addSentence(ChatAI.java:54)
    at shared.Initializer.main(Initializer.java:130)
```

I have never seen the (I)Z part before, does anyone know what this means? I already tried updating Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ***I have never seen the (I)Z part before, does anyone know what this means?***

The `(I)Z` part describes the argument and return type part of the method signature.

In this case it says that the method takes as argument an `int`, and returns a `boolean`.

Here's the complete list of such type notation:

```
V           void
Z           boolean
C           char
B           byte
S           short
I           int
F           float
J           long
D           double

L<class>;   Reference type, for example Ljava/lang/String;
```

---

<strike>It's hard to tell why the program runs fine on your computer. There is no method called `isAlphabetic` in the standard Java API.</strike>

The `Character.isAlphabetic` method was introduced in Java 7. It seems like you're running Java 7, and your friend has only Java 6 (or some lower version) installed.

Comment: Looks like a new method in Java 7. http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic%28int%29

Comment: @Mathew, ah, thanks. You taught me something today ;-) Answer updated.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I could have sworn that method was always there.

Answer (score 0):

User [aioobe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276052/aioobe) gave a nice explanation how to interpret this error message. It seems the referenced method was only [introduced in java7](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic(int)).